# How to set embeddings_data in TensorBoard in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: keras, callback, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0

For projector such as t-SNE, PCA in tensorboard, I could put data I wanted as a variable of embeddings_data in callbacks.TensorBoard in tensorflow 1.x 
However in tensorflow 2.0, the variable of embeddings_data is gone with embeddings_layer_name.
Instead Tensorflow 2.0 does project for all layer. 
However when I want specify the embeddings_data in TensorBoard, I have no idea how to define in Tensorflow2.0

**************************** TensorBoard in tensorflow 1.x *************************************

tb = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='.\logs',histogram_freq=1,write_graph=True,
                                 embeddings_freq=1,embeddings_layer_names=[dense_2], 
                                 embeddings_data=normal_train_data)

history = model.fit(
  normed_train_data, train_labels,
  epochs=EPOCHS, validation_split = 0.2, verbose=0,
  callbacks=[PrintDot()],tb )

---

**************************** TensorBoard in tensorflow 2.0 *************************************

tb = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='.\logs',histogram_freq=1,write_graph=True,
                                 embeddings_freq=1)

history = model.fit(
  normed_train_data, train_labels,
  epochs=EPOCHS, validation_split = 0.2, verbose=0,
  callbacks=[PrintDot()],tb )

---